# Customizing LoginButtons in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I am building a Login page in meteor. It has a facebook login button, gmail login button and linkedin login button. Then I have a Meteor's default login form.

Everything is fine so far. The only challenge is, I need to put all these social networking login buttons below my Meteor's default login form. How would I do that?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip using `accounts-ui` package and build the login page however  you want, with your UI design.

You can use can have buttons in whatever postiion you want with HTML and CSS.
But onclick event of those buttons just call `loginWith<Service>` methods ([link to doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice))

For login with facebook button, use

```
Template.myLogin.events({
   'click .facebook-login': function(){
      Meteor.loginWithFacebook(
         requestPermissions: ['email', 'user_about_me']
         }, function(err){
             if !err 
              console.log("Facebook login successful")
          }
      )
    }, 
    "click .twitter-login": function(){
       Meteor.loginWithTwitter(
         requestPermissions: ['email']
         }, function(err){
             if !err 
              console.log("Twitter login successful")
          }
       )
   }
})
```

For above to work, you need to add the first packages of concerned services like for facebook `accounts-facebook`, for twiter `accounts-twitter`

Comment: Is there any other way to edit the package code and keep the buttons at the end?

Comment: Editing package is not good idea but you may override CSS and hack something to get it done, but i would recommend doing above way instead

Comment: Did the above way, pretty helpful